# Java JMenuBar repainting background

Tags: java, swing, jpanel, repaint, jmenubar

Lately I've been experementing with java and swing and I run into a problem

I have a "Welcome screen" with some random generated background.

I overrided paintComponent and made it painting the background based on current JPanel's resolution. Not something fancy just ovals

[image: before]

But when I use menu, the background of menu is repainted.

[image: after]

The size and potision of ovals are based on screens resolution.
There is any way to solve?

NOTE: welcome panel is JPanel

Comment: Where is your code? Post your code in the question, see [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Which part of code you really need? Is just a paintComponent method with randoms()

Comment: a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example so we can compile and run it...

Comment: @LittleJacod what DavidPostill is trying to tell you is create a new project (a copy of the original one) and take out all unnecessary code, such as actionListeners, colors, etc (in case not needed, but this case they are needed), but still reproduce the issue. In order that we can copy-paste it and actually see the problem you see and be more able to help you.

Comment: @Frakcool I can understand what he is saying my this is 3 classes code its not so hard to understand what i am saying... And i got my answer without posting any code. how this people got it?

Comment: @LittleJacod yes this time you were lucky someone answered your question w/o code, but mostly of times you **must** share an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) in order to get better (and faster) answers. It's just a recommendation for further questions you may ask.

Comment: I'm curious, have you even attempted my answer? If you don't want the circles to change, that's the way to go. Like I said, don't do the random operation in the paint method. Create the circles outside the method

Comment: @peeskillet didn't tried it, the other answer was fine and faster to implement. anyway thk for your answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That happens because area under PopUpMenu redraw after closing popUp, but other area doesn't.

You can repaint your panel after closing popUp like next :

```
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.util.Random;

import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JMenu;
import javax.swing.JMenuBar;
import javax.swing.JMenuItem;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JPopupMenu;
import javax.swing.event.PopupMenuEvent;
import javax.swing.event.PopupMenuListener;


public class TestFrame extends JFrame {

    public TestFrame() {
        init();
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        pack();
        setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        setVisible(true);
    }

    private void init() {
        DrawPanel p = new DrawPanel();
        add(p);

        JMenuBar bar = new JMenuBar();
        JMenu menu = new JMenu("menu");
        JPopupMenu popupMenu = menu.getPopupMenu();
        popupMenu.addPopupMenuListener(new PopupMenuListener() {

            @Override
            public void popupMenuWillBecomeVisible(PopupMenuEvent arg0) {

            }

            @Override
            public void popupMenuWillBecomeInvisible(PopupMenuEvent arg0) {
                repaint();
            }

            @Override
            public void popupMenuCanceled(PopupMenuEvent arg0) {

            }
        });
        bar.add(menu);
        menu.add(new JMenuItem("item"));
        setJMenuBar(bar);
    }


    public static void main(String args[]) {
        new TestFrame();
    }


    private class DrawPanel extends JPanel{

        @Override
        public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
            return new Dimension(100,100);
        }

        @Override
        protected void paintComponent(Graphics arg0) {
            super.paintComponent(arg0);

            Random r = new Random();
            int nextInt = r.nextInt(20);
            arg0.drawOval(nextInt, nextInt, 20, 20);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks that work. But it repaint the whole window again but i guess there is no other way

Comment: You can repaint just target `JPanel` with ellipses.

Comment: This is not a correct solution. See my extended answer, please!

Answer (score 0):

Draw your background on a bitmap, and copy it in the `paintComponent()` method. The paint event can occur "at any time", and in this case your random source generates new values.

Another solution: make a method `getRandom()` which creates a `Random` object with the same seed, and use this. For example:

```
  protected long seed = 0L;

  protected void initRandom() { // call this in constructing time
      seed = Calendar.getInstance().getTimeInMillis();
  }

  protected Random getRandom() { // call this at the start of the painting method
      return new Random(seed);
  }
```

This creates new seed for all window instance, and uses it consistently. Any repaint will make no unwanted effect.